# jQuery in Brackets Live Preview not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, adobe-brackets

I have the beginning of I note taking website I am making as an experiment. It was working fine in the live preview from brackets, but then I saved the files and now none of the jQuery works. I think it is my code by it could also be something with Brackets since it only happened once I saved. Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var notes = [];

  $("#newNoteWrapper").hide();

  $(".text").focus(function() {

    $(this).stop
    $(this).animate({
      marginLeft: "+=3%"
    });

  });
  $(".text").blur(function() {

    $(this).stop
    $(this).animate({
      marginLeft: "-=3%"
    });

  });

  $(".button").hover(function() {

    $(this).stop();
    $(this).animate({
      backgroundColor: "#108cb1"
    }, 200);

  }, function() {

    $(this).stop()
    $(this).animate({
      backgroundColor: "#2DBEEB"
    }, 200);

  });

  $("#newNoteButton").click(function() {

    newNote(true);

  });


  $("#doneButton").click(function() {

    newNote(false);

  });
});

var newNote = function(enter) {

  if enter {
    $("#newNoteWrapper").show();
  } else {
    $("#newNoteWrapper").hide();
    notes.push({
      title: $("#noteTitle").val(),
      body: $("#noteBody").val(),
    });
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.button {
  padding: 15px 25px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #2DBEEB;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  outline: none;
}
.text {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 92%;
  border-left: 10px solid #2DBEEB;
  resize: vertical;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
#newNoteButton {
  margin: 10px;
}
#newNoteWrapper {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  top: 0%;
}
#newNote {
  background-color: #2DBEEB;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
#noteTitle {
  font-size: 25px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}
#noteBody {
  font-size: 12pt;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
}
#doneButton {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="notes.css">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.color-animation/1/mainfile"></script>
  <script src="notes.js"></script>
  <title>Simple Notes</title>
</head>

<body>

  <button id="newNoteButton" class="button">new note</button>
  <div id="newNoteWrapper">
    <div id="newNote">new note</div>
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="noteTitle" class="text" placeholder="title..."></input>
      <textarea id="noteBody" class="text" placeholder="body..."></textarea>
      <br />
      <button id="doneButton" class="button">done</button>
    </form>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Is there something wrong with this or should I try a different editor?

Comment: Look at your console in the Dev Tools, you have a syntax error: `if enter {`, also you forgot `()` after your first two `$(this).stop` lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must edit the follwing of

In HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.color-animation/1/mainfile"></script>
```

In JS

```
var newNote = function(enter) {

   if (enter) {
      $("#newNoteWrapper").show();
   } else {
      $("#newNoteWrapper").hide();
      notes.push({
         title: $("#noteTitle").val(),
         body: $("#noteBody").val(),
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: I fixed this, and it still does not work. I noticed that if I `alert("test")` outside of `$(document).ready(function() {` it works, but if it is inside, it does not.